# Template syntax error. Could not parse the remainder (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can someone point me to the right direction? Below is what I have been doing

```
    <p>{{article.snippet}}</p>
    <p>{{article.date}}</p>
    <p>{{article.retrieve_by_category("web")}}</p>
```

I have no problems getting the date or the snippet but I keep getting the following error when trying to run `article.retireve_by_category`.

> Could not parse the remainder: **'("web")' from 'article.retrieve_by_category("web")'**

Below is the code for the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #add in thumbnail

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:500] + "..."

    def retrieve_by_category(self,category):
        """retrieves blogs based on their category"""
        if (str(self.category) == category):
            return self.category
        return ''
```

Comment: That function doesn't appear to do anything useful anyway. It certainly doesn't do what the name implies. It all you want to do is to check a category name, you could do it directly in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call functions inside the template. It's best to handle it in your views ,Below is a simple example:

```
def your_view(request):

   article = Article.objects.filter(category="web")

   return render(request, "/toyourtemplate", {'web':article})
```

If you want to make the category dynamic user input, you can use django forms

Answer (score 0):

You can not use functions as similar to template tags

```
<p>{{article.snippet}}</p>
<p>{{article.date}}</p>
<p>{{article.retrieve_by_category("web")}}</p>  # this is wrong
```

Instead of that you can make your [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).